# Autocomplete search by First Name and Last Name

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I have created an autosuggestion search box using PHP and jQuery. The user is prompted to insert First name and Last name to find someone that exists in my database, in a table called `customers`. Table `customers` holds 2 columns, `first_name` and `last_name`.

My search works fine when you type the First name but after pressing space to move and type Last Name does not give any results. The whole problem seems to appear when pressing space button. Any idea how to fix it?

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $("#customers").autocomplete({
    source: "fetch_customers.php?cc=<?php echo $agencyid; ?>",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var code = ui.item.id;
      if (code != '#') {
        location.href = '/view-customer/' + code;
      }
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```php
<?php
  $countrycode1 = $_GET['cc'];
  $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])); 
  $term = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $term);

  $a_json = array();
  $a_json_row = array();

  $a_json_invalid = array(array("id" => "#", "value" => $term, "label" => "Only letters and digits are permitted..."));
  $json_invalid = json_encode($a_json_invalid);

  if ($data = $conn->query("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE agency_id='$countrycode1' AND (first_name LIKE '%$term%' OR last_name LIKE '%$term%') ORDER BY first_name , last_name")) 
  {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) 
    {
      $firstname = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['first_name']));
      $lastname = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['last_name']));
      $code = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
      $a_json_row["id"] = $code;
      $a_json_row["value"] = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
      $a_json_row["label"] = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
      array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
    }
  }

  /* jQuery wants JSON data */
  $json = json_encode($a_json);
  print $json;
  flush();
  $conn->close();
```

Comment: Altering the query with a concat function will help?

Comment: You should either split `$term` at ' ' and query `first_name`, `last_name` with separate values. Or you should query your database with a more complicated query: get a column with merged values `first_name + ' ' + last_name` and after that compare it with `$term`.

Comment: any sample codes to help me with?

Comment: Try replacing $term = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $term); with $term = preg_replace('/\b[\w-]+\b/', ' ', $term);

Comment: @hans-konig, no thats not working.

Comment: I am thinking of creating a view in the db with first_name and last_name concatenation.

Comment: what about this :   $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])); 
  preg_match_all('/\b[\w-]+\b/', $term, $words);
  $term = $words[0] . ' ' . $words[1];

Comment: You should be using prepared statements. @cray was right you need to split the term by space or concat a column with both. Splitting the term would probably be easier.

Comment: @hans-könig, no that script is also not working.

Comment: @Second2None. Thank you. will try that

Comment: @hans-könig, its showing 2 errors. One is Array to string conversion error and Undefined offset error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Split Your $term like this.

```
$splited_term = explode(" ",$term);
$first_term = $splited_term[0];
$last_term = (isset($splited_term[1]) && !empty($splited_term)) ? $splited_term[1] : null;
```

Generate your query according

```
$query = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE agency_id='$countrycode1' AND ";

if(!empty($first_term)){
     $query.= "(first_name LIKE '%$first_term%' OR last_name LIKE '%$first_term%'" ;
}
if(!empty($last_term)){
  $query  .= ((!empty($first_term)) ? " OR " : " ( " )." first_name LIKE '%$last_term%' OR last_name LIKE '%$last_term%')" ;
}

$query .= ((empty($last_term)) ? ")" : "")." ORDER BY first_name , last_name";
```

This will support

1. "Milind Patel"
2. "Patel Milind"
3. " Milind"
4. " Patel"
5. "Milind"
6. "Patel"

So Your code should be like this.

```
<?php
  $countrycode1 = $_GET['cc'];
  $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term'])); 
  $term = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $term);

  $splited_term = explode(" ",$term);
  $first_term = $splited_term[0];
  $last_term = (isset($splited_term[1]) && !empty($splited_term)) ? $splited_term[1] : null;

  $a_json = array();
  $a_json_row = array();

  $a_json_invalid = array(array("id" => "#", "value" => $term, "label" => "Only letters and digits are permitted..."));
  $json_invalid = json_encode($a_json_invalid);

  $query = "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE agency_id='$countrycode1' AND ";

  if(!empty($first_term)){
    $query.= "(first_name LIKE '%$first_term%' OR last_name LIKE '%$first_term%'" ;
  }
  if(!empty($last_term)){
    $query  .= ((!empty($first_term)) ? " OR " : " ( " )." first_name LIKE '%$last_term%' OR last_name LIKE '%$last_term%')" ;
  }

  $query .= ((empty($last_term)) ? ")" : "")." ORDER BY first_name , last_name";

  if ($data = $conn->query($query)) 
  {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) 
    {
      $firstname = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['first_name']));
      $lastname = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['last_name']));
      $code = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['id']));
      $a_json_row["id"] = $code;
      $a_json_row["value"] = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
      $a_json_row["label"] = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
      array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
    }
  }

  /* jQuery wants JSON data */
  $json = json_encode($a_json);
  print $json;
  flush();
  $conn->close();
```

Comment: Let me check @ Milind.

Comment: showing an error now in the following line:
$last_term = (isset($splited_term[1]) && !empty($splited_term)) $splited_term[1] : null;

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$splited_term' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Still there is an error in this line of code $last_term = (isset($splited_term[1]) && !empty($splited_term)) $splited_term[1] : null;
Error states that : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$splited_term

Comment: No that line has not changed and am getting the same error.

Comment: same error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$splited_term'

Comment: StackOverflow Editor killing me. 

Please check now we are just missing "?" in the line. Sorry for that syntax thing.